# Search result pagination not working well...search is working but paging causing errors in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My pagination of search results is not working. It's showing result but pagination making it random. Please help me. Search is working but can't apply pagination in it, it's getting complicated

search_products_model

```
<?php
class search_products_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
        {
               parent::__construct();
        }
    public function get_results($search_term,$limit, $offset)
    {
        // Use the Active Record class for safer queries.       
         $this->db->like('name',$search_term);

        // Execute the query.
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_products',$limit, $offset);    

         if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
         {
           return $query->result_array();
         }
         else
         {
    return FALSE;
         }
        // Return the results.            
    }

       function get_products_id($id)
        {
         $this->db->where('prod_id',$id);
          $query = $this->db->get('tbl_products');
           return $query->result(); 
        }         
}
?>   

controller

<?php
class search_products extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email','pagination'));
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('search_products_model');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->search_products();
        $this->load->view('search_products_view');   
    }
    function display_registration_form()
    {        
     $this->load->view('search_products_view');   
    }

     function execute_search($offset = 0) 
    {    
        $config['base_url'] = '/mehmaa/index.php/search_products/execute_search/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results('tbl_products');
        $config['per_page'] = 6; 
         $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';             

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
       // Retrieve the posted search term.
       $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $search_term = $this->input->post('term');  
        // Use a model to retrieve the results.
        $data['results'] = $this->search_products_model->get_results($search_term,$config['per_page'], $offset);  

        if ( empty($data['results']) ) 
    {                       
                 $this->load->view('search_products_view');   
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'No results found');    
    }
        else{
        // Pass the results to`enter code here` the view.            
        $this->load->view('search_results',$data);          
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

hi in this link you are not checking the search condition

```
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results('tbl_products');
```

change this line to

```
 $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results($search_term);
```

and write the proper query

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results('tbl_products');
```

Problem in the this files, u need write another query which will be collect result by search without offsets and limits.
For example

```
function search($text, $offset, $limits){
  //this u do search
}

function count_search($text){
   //This same logic with search but return Integer value for example
   //return $this->db->query()->num_rows();
}
```